# WebView isn't loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I am encountering a problem in my Android application where when I open up webview, nothing shows up.  It's just white.  Here is my code:

```
private void AddListenerOnButton() {
    spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

            if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {          
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
                    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   



            }
```

What is happening here?  I have imported all the right JAR files.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, beside the

```
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

it says that

```
The value of the local variable newsHeadlines is not used
```

What do I have to do then?  I am a beginner in Android.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Um, there's no `WebView` here.

Comment: Wait, I'll put up the whole code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I put up the whole code

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do then?

Well, if nothing else, you have to tell the `WebView` to show something. You have configured it, but you have not called `loadUrl()`, `loadData()`, or `loadDataWithBaseURL()` to tell `WebView` what to display.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this.  I have checked all over Google in trying to find the answer.  Can you post sample code?

Comment: @user2507301: I do not know what "this" is. `loadUrl()` is a method. You call it on a `WebView`, passing it a URL as a string (e.g., `webView.loadUrl("http://commonsware.com");`).

Comment: I only need part of the webpage.  If I do loadUrl, it brings the whole webpage.

Comment: @user2507301: Then create the HTML, as a string, of what you want to show, and pass it to `loadData()`. The second parameter to `loadData()` would be `"text/html"` (since your string is holding HTML), and the third parameter is probably `"UTF-8"` (for the encoding).